# Re-merge reverted changes from a branch into master on Github?

Tags: git, github, merge, revert

I have two branches, `bb` and `master`.  I worked on `bb`, made some changes, pushed them to Github, and made a pull request that I merged into `master`.  I then saw a problem with a production app and thought there was a problem with the changes in `bb`, so I clicked the `revert` button on Github.

It turned out that the problem was not with the code but with a data file that was needed by the changes in `bb` that I hadn't uploaded to the server, so I wanted the changes from `bb` merged into master after all ... so, I made a meaningless change in `bb` (added some whitespace) to get a new PR.  But the PR was just for the whitespace, not for all the other changes in `bb` relative to `master`.  I merged the PR, but sure enough only the whitespace change was applied.

So now Github has two versions of a file `foo.py`, one in `bb` and one in `master`, and when I try to make a pull request, it tells me that "There isn’t anything to compare. `master` is up to date with all commits from `bb`".  Huh?

How can I get Github to actually merge the changes from `foo.py` in `bb` into `master`?  (I think it's thrown off because it has previously merged exactly these changes ... but the current state of `foo.py` in `master` is different from in `bb`.)

Answer (score 3):

Your easiest fix is to head to the terminal. Checkout the project if you haven't already.

```
git clone <url> my_project
cd my_project
git log (Find the id of the revert-- which is just a commit)
git revert (commit_id)
```

Then push your changes to bb and create a pull request for master

Comment: I can't revert the revert at this point because other people working on other branches have pushed changes to master that I would clobber.

Crap, I think I just realized the problem.  The problem is that the changes in `bb` are older than the changes in `master`.  The only thing I can think of now is to do something really hacky like change `foo.py` to an empty file and commit and push, and then put the changes back in `foo.py` and I'll get the PR I want.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Technically the commit is already in master. You could merge master into your branch and then make the changes. But I think you might be better off to create a new branch and then make the changes again. You could cherrypick the commit, but then you would end up back in the same spot. Because the commit is in master. So either merge master in and make the change or create a new branch off of master and make the changes.

Comment: Your changes will be in the history of the file. So I would just create a new branch do a compare with my old commit and grab the changes. Then commit and push. Create pull request and you are done.

Comment: The correct answer really is to revert the revert.  It's important to realize that `git revert <ID>` does *not* mean "go back to the *state* as of `<ID>`".  Revert turns a given commit ID into a patch and then "reverse-applies" the patch.  Thus, if the change in `<ID>` was "remove line 17 of file X, change line 5 of file Y, and add new line 9 to file Z", reverting it means "put back line 17 in X, un-change 5 in Y, remove 9 in Z" (except that it is all done with context diffs and patching, which will require your help to merge if something else changed in or next to those lines).